# CloudFront: The specified bucket does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website hosted on S3 which works fine when accessed through my bucket's endpoint. However, when I create a CloudFront distribution and try access it through using the CloudFront domain I keep getting the error below.

```
d1xu3mknlk0sbd.cloudfront.net

Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: d1xu3mknlk0sbd.cloudfront.net
RequestId: 656B653A2ED5B2B1
HostId: 9etNAX1XEJmbVKUAMylBDz3xEky+7RhAnr9b8HhpkIb9+pkMnn920v/MSAUjr78oyONEUdlba50=
```

I have set up my CloudFront origin domain name to the s3 url of my static site which works when I type it in the browser so why can't CloudFront find the bucket ...

Comment: Did you name your bucket actually `d1xu3mknlk0sbd.cloudfront.net`? Probably not as the name is random.

Comment: That is my Cloudfront Domain name serving my s3 bucket

Comment: The error message says its bucketname: `BucketName: d1xu3mknlk0sbd.cloudfront.net`. Can you double check that please?

Comment: No it's not. I configured my origin to my s3 bucket using the dropdown so not sure why it is looking there. I also have another distribution running using the same settings which strangely works ..

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up solving this by changing my s3 bucket name from 'sample' to 'www.sample.com' .Strangely CloudFront started resolving the correct bucket name. Why this works remains a mystery ...

Comment: It works! some how you need the 'www' included in the bucket name.